# SharePoint SQL DB is nearly 50 GB. Cannot shrink due to lost/expired SA password

Tags: sql, windows-sbs-2008, sharepoint-2007

Back in June of last year I posted about how [our old SharePoint '07 database has grown exorbitantly large](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1654771-sharepoint_config-ldf-log-file-is-too-big-22-gbs-how-to-shrink-it). The problem is that C:\ and E:\ are on a single VMDK and the C:\ parition is nearly out of room (only about 6 GB left!). I don't want to try and resize the partitions because I am afraid it will break (what effectively is) our PDC.

I'm also trying [SQL query commands from this site](http://network-nick.blogspot.com/2011/11/sbs-2008-c-drive-runs-out-of-space.html) (via SQL server mgmt Studio 08), but they also do not work due to lack of permissions.

So now I'm trying to do this: https://webblah.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/how-to-shrink-the-sharepoint-config-database-log-file-on-a-...

...but the file just returns this:
`C:\>sqlcmd -S \\.\pipe\mssql$microsoft##ssee\sql\query -E -i c:\logshrink.sql
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server OLD-SBS-SERVER\MICROSOFT##SSEE, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '?'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server OLD-SBS-SERVER\MICROSOFT##SSEE, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '?'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server OLD-SBS-SERVER\MICROSOFT##SSEE, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'â'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server OLD-SBS-SERVER\MICROSOFT##SSEE, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '?'.
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Server OLD-SBS-SERVER\MICROSOFT##SSEE, Line 7
Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'â?~ + RTRIM(@COnfigDB) + â?
~'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.`

I cannot seem to get the SQLCMD -S . command to work. What can I do here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution. I had to go into "SQL Server Configuration Manager" (for SQL Svr 2005, in my case) > SQL Server network Configuration > Protocols for MICROSOFT##SSEE: **TCP/IP - ENABLED**, then restart the MICROSOFT##SSEE database (under SQL Server Services in SSCM).

Here's a helpful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

After doing that I was able to Open "SQL Server Surface Area Configuration" and add the Domain Admin as a SysAdmin for the DB, then all the SQL query commands worked.